# Ubuntu image file has no source

Tags: data-recovery, restore

I got a backup of holiday pictures on my external hard drive, but some JPGs are data only. If I execute the *file* command, I get e.g.

```
2015-09-15_07:49:22.JPG:       JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=14, manufacturer=Panasonic, model=DMC-LF1, orientation=upper-left, xresolution=200, yresolution=208, resolutionunit=2, software=Ver.1.2  , datetime=2015:09:15 07:49:23], baseline, precision 8, 4000x3000, components 3

2015-09-15_07:49:32.JPG:       data
```

As you can see the second image is somehow damaged. How can I restore the files?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Likely the header of the image is corrupt. So, data exists but header is broken.

A couple things to try:

- Rename the JPEG. This works in a lot of cases.
- Re save from an image editor like PhotoShop or Gimp. Sometimes resaving the file will fix the headers.
- Sometimes bad sectors on the disk can cause this. Try running fsck on Ubuntu or CHKSDSK ( from Windows command line ) on the drive.

  sudo fsck /dev/sdb

Comment: How to run CHKDSK when this is an Ubuntu forum? ;-)

Comment: Good point. Try fsck.

Comment: fsck doesnt help, images still have the wrong header and happy new year ;)

gimp wont open the images :(